# Eclipse Juno Weird Characters appearing

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I think I pressed something when I was working on Android app. Weird characters appeared and I can figure out how to get rid of them. They are distracting when I am trying to code. Can some one help. I got a screen shot of some of the characters.
[image]

Not sure what hotkeys I pressed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `show whitespace characters` turned on, this is set on `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors`

Comment: thanks... for future people.. its the paragraph icon on the toolbar also